# Proving $\Omega$ Notation

Tags: asymptotics

Prove the following:

$$ \frac{n^2}{4} \log ^2 \left(\frac{n}{4}\right) = \Omega \left(\frac{n^2}{2} \log ^2 \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\right)$$

Whatever I try to do gets me nowhere, I tried multiplying both sides by $\dfrac{2}{n^2}$ and got to the inequality:
$$\frac{\log^2 (\frac{n}{4})}{\log^2 (\frac{n}{2})} \geq 2c$$
$$\frac{(\log n-2)^2}{(\log n-1)^2} \geq 2c$$

But that leads me nowhere.

Comment: When you prove something you should start by one side and end by the other.

Comment: @user689, but I need to find intuition for choosing the $n_0, c > 0$ for the $\Omega$ notation proof

Comment: Does $[ \cdot ]$ stand for integer part?

Comment: I'm not sure I got you @Alex, what do you mean by *integer part*?

Comment: $[3.5]=3$ for example

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html

Comment: @Alex, oh no no, sorry, those are regular brackets. I just didn't want people to get confused with all of the brackets in the omega side. I know what it means, just not in English :)

Comment: Then what you are trying to prove is $f(x)=\Omega(f(x))$

Comment: @Alex, mind the denominator is 4 on the LHS and 2 on the RHS

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem using limits for these kind of proofs? Or do you have to use the definition?

Comment: @Code-Guru, I am familiar with the limits theorem, but sadly I was supposed to use the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote for simplicity $\log n =t$. From your last expression we need to find for what $t$ this holds. Solve the inequality 
$$
(1-2 c_1) t^2 +(4c_1-2)t +4 -2 c_1 \geq 0
$$
and select the positive root

Comment: I solved it in another way, by simplifying LHS and then making it smaller (which is legit in omega proofs) to the stage where I could simply equate both LHS and RHS with some limitations on $n$.